# How to import Facebook SDK into my android eclipse project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I'm a bit confused between 2 screen in eclipse:

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure how to import FB sd into my Android project properly.

What does "android" mean vs "Java build path" ?

As current configuration I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says - there are 2 versions of a jar - android-support-v4.jar. Either make FB use your version of android-support-v4 or use FB's version of android-support-v4.jar in your project. The jar will be in project-name/libs folder.

Comment: What does "android" mean vs "Java build path" ?

Comment: I know that, i can see myself. but why did I do wrong to make this?

Comment: Using the Android tab, you can set the Android version that your project is supposed to run on, along with other settings such as the libraries to go with your project. Using the java build path, you specify the use of java libraries or external jars that your project can use. Generally, this is where you specify which version of a jar is to be used and also which version is to be given precedence over other versions (using order and export)

Comment: `libraries to go with your project` and `external jars that your project can use` it seems redundant. no?

Comment: Nope...just take the case of android-support-v4.jar. If you need to add the latest version, say android-support-v13, then you would need to do so using the java build path tab.

Comment: still don't get this. wouldn't i have to change under "android" tab for support-v13 as well? both build and android path. no?

Comment: The Android tab is for adding Android libraries. For adding any other jars, you have to use the build path tab. And no, you need not change anything under Android tab if you added a jar using the build-path tab.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the problem, the picture is too small, also, Facebook has a great [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) about how to do just that, also, make sure you're using Facebook's android support jar.

Comment: What does "android" mean vs "Java build path" ?

Answer (score 0):

First import it as a project into your eclipse and then give its reference to your project as you have shown in your first screen. If you have only jars file then add those jar to your **libs** folder and then follow steps of add to build path.

Comment: What does "android" mean vs "Java build path" ?

Comment: @user1065869 it means  adding the jars to the classpath

Answer (score 0):

Delete the  `android-support-v4.jar`  from your project as there will be a jar mismatch.As you have added Facebook SDK as a library project, it is again not required to add that support jar file.Facebook SDK already contain that library.If `android-support-v4.jar` is a older one then  you can update it.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 android support library with different keys.
Right click on your FacebokSDK and project ---> Android tools ---> Add support Library